# Rewrite a post type archive slug based on if more than 1 post exists

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, archive, permalinks, slug

Is there a way to write/rewrite a post type archive slug based on if more than 1 post exists?

For example my CPT is locations what I want to achieve is if there is only one location, the url is:

[www.URL.com/location/](http://www.URL.com/location/)

If there are 2 or more locations the archive url is:

[www.URL.com/locations/](http://www.URL.com/locations/)

Comment: Just thinking SEO wised, that's a bad idea

Comment: @amarinediary Why do you think this would be bad for SEO? if you have one location, it should be singular?

Comment: SEO wised just regarding the indexing, as soon as a post types as more than one you're asking google to delete your previous post type path and create a new one. Pages that are listed on Google will take quite some time to be removed and risk of 404 error will increase. Simple example of my pov would be, a user type www.URL.com/locations/ (with an S), which was the url before but end up to a 404 page because the url is actually now www.URL.com/location/ (with no S). Sure you could manage that with redirection but still you would register a 404 error. There is a reason nobody does it...